# can't print ObjectID structure

Tags: node.js

I'm doing this in nodejs:

```
var bson = require("bson");
var util = require("util");
var obj = new bson.ObjectID();
console.log( util.inspect( obj, {showHidden:true, depth:5 } ) );
```

it should print the structure of ObjectID object, i'm expecting to see functions and properties in console, however all that i see is a hexstring like 530b7870164068e4b9fd353c.

Any help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

util.inspect will call an object's custom inspect() function when one has been defined, which is the case for the ObjectID type. Check out line 137 in the bson module's /lib/bson/objectid.js:

```
/**
* Converts to a string representation of this Id.
*
* @return {String} return the 24 byte hex string representation.
* @api private
*/
ObjectID.prototype.inspect = ObjectID.prototype.toString;
```

Had this custom inspector not been set, you would have seen a print of the kind of data you expected. A simple test can confirm: comment out this line setting the ObjectID's custom inspector on the ObjectID prototype, and your sample code above now produces something like this:

```
{ _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
id: 'S\u000b~öxÿOkü6ü',
binId: <Buffer 53 0b 7e 99 f6 78 ff 4f 6b fc 36 fc> }
```

Cheers.

Comment: exactly ! this is what i was looking for https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/bson/objectid.js#L135
thanks.